# Prism.js in Angular works for the first code block (Code syntax highlighting)

Tags: angular, prismjs

**[According to this article](https://auralinna.blog/post/2017/code-syntax-highlighting-with-angular-and-prismjs)**

After installing the following package

```
npm install prismjs --save
```

Then I created a service named: HighlightService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar';
import 'prismjs/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/prism-copy-to-clipboard';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-css';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-javascript';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-java';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-markup';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-typescript';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-sass';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-scss';

declare var Prism: any;

@Injectable()
export class HighlightService {
    constructor() { }

    highlightAll() {
        Prism.highlightAll();
    }
}
```

I used service above in the component as below:

```
export class AdminBlogDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ... 

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.highlightService.highlightAll();
  }

}
```

And finally, add the following SCSS on the top of style.scss:

```
@import "~prismjs/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.css";
@import "~prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia";
```

My problem is that above service works for the first block of code in the page!

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9z4xaq)

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: My problem is that above service applies on the first block in the page!

Comment: can you create a working example using a `stackblitz`

Comment: DEMO:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9z4xaq

Comment: your missing `class="language-javascript"` property to the `code` tag